Did I prove using Cartan's Magic formula that the flow of this vector field locally preserves volume?
(a) State Cartan’s formula for the Lie derivative of a differential form with respect to a vector field.
(b) Use this formula to show that the flow generated (locally) by a vector field $ X $ on $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ preserves volume if and only if the divergence of $ X $ is everywhere zero. (Here, divergence is the classical operator that takes a vector field with components $ f, g, h $ to the function $ \partial_x f + \partial_y g + \partial_z h $, where $ x, y, z $ are the usual coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My answer for part (a):
$L_X (\omega)$ is the Lie Derivative of some form $\omega$ along a vector field $X$.
$\iota_X (\omega)$ is the interior multiplication of a vector field $X$ with a differential form
Then Cartan's magic formula for some vector field $X$ is given by:
$$ \boxed{ \; L_X (\omega) = \iota_X  (d \omega) + d (\iota_x \omega) \; }$$

My answer for part (b):
We'll prove the forward $(\implies)$ case first. We can measure the volume of some arbitrary 3-vector $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ as such:
$$ \text{(volume of 3-vector)} = (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) (v_1, v_2, v_3)$$
To write our proof we can technically use any nonzero 3-vector that we want. For simplicity we'll canonically represent our 3-vector as being the unit $(e_x , e_y, e_z)$. Thus our volume is simply:
$$ (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)(e_x , e_y, e_z) = 1$$
For our vector field $X$ to (locally) preserve volume, we know that volume must be constant; when we measure the volume with our form $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$, we must return the same number throughout. Consequently, the rate of change in our measured volume along a vector field must be zero. Then
$$\left( L_X (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) \right)(e_x , e_y , e_z) = 0 $$
Recall that our vector $X$ is given in terms of $X = (f, g, h)$. Now expand the factor $L_X (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)$:
\begin{align}
L_X (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) &= \iota_x (d (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)) + d (\iota_X \, (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)) \\\\ &= 0  + d(f \, dy \wedge dz - g \, dx \wedge dz + h \, dx \wedge dy) \\\\ &= \partial_x f \, dx \wedge dy \wedge dz - \partial_y g \, dy \wedge dx \wedge dz + \partial_z h \, dz \wedge dx \wedge dy \\\\ &= \left( \partial x f + \partial _y g + \partial_z h \right)(dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)
\end{align}
Knowing that the rate of change of our volume must be measure zero:
\begin{align}
\left( L_X (dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) \right)(e_x , e_y , e_z) &= \left( \partial x f + \partial _y g + \partial_z h \right)(dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)(e_x , e_y , e_z) \\\\ &= \boxed{ \; \partial x f + \partial _y g + \partial_z h = 0 \;} 
\end{align}
To prove the backward case $(\impliedby)$, simply start from this answer, work backwards algebraically, and then apply the reasoning of the forward case in reverse to show that the volume is locally conserved. QED

Seems alright to me! You might want to note that this result is also true for $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2724125/261022.
